# UITableViewCell not appearing in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have an app that I am migrating to iOS7. In my app I have a subclass of UITableViewController that I feed a Array of NSDictionaires in order fill.
This class has worked without a hitch on previous versions of iOS 7.

But since I started editing it in XCode 5 the UITableViewCells aren't showing. The section headers are, and the 'placement' of the cells also seems correct.

When I output the cell returned by cellForRowAtIndex in a NSLog I get:

```
2013-09-27 14:53:00.008 MyApp[25278:a0b] Cell for: <UITableViewCell: 0xc5f7ca0; frame = (0 681; 703 40); text = 'Status'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xc5f7e30>>
```

I have switched to using a cell from the StoryBoard but that did not help.
Even when I change cellForRowAtIndex to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";
return cell;
```

I get nothing.
I've removed everything in my viewWillAppear & viewDidLoad methods. But that had no impact.
I also created a new TableViewController subclass. And that displays cells without issue when using the above code.
Does anyone have any idea what might be causing my cells to disappear?

Comment: Is you identifier actually just "Cell"? You should give it a unique name in Storyboard, than set it in here as well

Comment: Need more code to tell, you could be losing your data somehow. Maybe a stray reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Always happens when you ask for help.
In the method where I set the object for the tableview Datasource I had the following lines:

```
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

I'm not even sure why I have that in there, probably because I was not dequeueing, which I wasn't doing at first because there was a limited amount of cells and each cell was of a different style.
I covered the different styles by using multiple designs in my storyboard and using a different identifier when dequeueing.

Comment: What do you mean with that? If you mean what IDE I always use XCode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355545/swift-reuse-cells-in-ios7-1-simulator-cells-are-hidden i have a similar problem but my cells don't get properly updated if i remove this part. (except mine is cell.view.subviews)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered your cell either by creating it in your nib or storyboard or using one of these methods in your table init code:

```
– registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
– registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this approach. In your code what if tableView deque.. method return no cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Comment: This is the "old" approach. If you create your cell in a nib with the table or storyboard you no longer need to 'init' manually. Also see my post for the current correct way of doing this (ie registering cells).